# Use Host VPN in Guest VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

I have a host Windows 7 OS running a guest Lubuntu OS in VirtualBox and I'm trying to configure it so that the Guest OS will use the Host VPN.

So a couple quirks, when the VPN is turned off the guest internet connection will work however when the VPN is turned on it seems to be blocking traffic from the guest. Nothing I've found so far has provided a complete solution.

Extra Info:

- VBox is currently configured to use NAT.
- VPN is using Cisco AnyConnect 4.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open an admin console on your windows7 host and execute the following:

```
$ VBoxManage list vms
```

Note that uuid or name in parenthesis of your VM and then:

```
$ VBoxManage modifyvm <uuid or name here> --natdnshostresolver1 on
```

Note that your VM needs to be turned off before you execute the above command.

Comment: Some notes: 
1. You need to perform `cd C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` before executing commands.; 
2. If I am correct, that settings will work only if you set "NAT" as network adapter type in your VM's settings.

Comment: 3. You can enable `natdnsproxy1` instead of `natdnshostresolver1`, or enable them both. Differences between them discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060639/virtualbox-what-is-the-difference-of-natdnsproxy1-and-natdnshostresolver1